# Sitecore GetChildren empty just after child item created

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sitecore, sitecore-speak-ui

I have a Sitecore.Services.Client API controller wired up to a Sitecore SPEAK application that uploads a media item (CSV) then parses the CSV and imports the data.

Once this import is complete I create a summary item within Sitecore that contains a list of items created, any errors, a link to the CSV uploaded.

```cs
var parentItem = _itemReader.GetItem(ParentItemId);
var template = _itemReader.GetTemplateItem(TemplateId);

var newItem = parentItem.Add(title, template);
```

I then have another controller that looks at the summary item folder get the children where the media ID is the item I have uploaded.

```cs
summaryFolder.Children.Where(x => x["Media file"] == mediaItemId).FirstOrDefault();
```

The issue i'm seeing is that once the one controller has created the item, the next controller is calling Item.Children however no children are found. If i request the controller again later they are found. It appears like the Item cache potentially or something similar isn't updating in time.

Is there anyway to request an item bypassing any caching and go directly to the database. Or is there anyway when i create the item to force the cache to update?

Full code

```cs
public ImportAudit GetLatestAudit(string mediaItemId)
{
        var importAudit = new ImportAudit();

        var summaryFolder = masterDatabase.GetItem(new ID(AuditFolderId));

        if (summaryFolder != null)
        {
            var lastestAudit = summaryFolder.GetChildren().Where(x => x["Media file"] == mediaItemId).OrderByDescending(x => x.Statistics.Created).FirstOrDefault();

            if (lastestAudit != null)
            {
                importAudit.ImportedItems = GetTitles(lastestAudit, "Imported Items");
            }
        }

        return importAudit;
    }
```

Comment: Do you use `.GetChildren()` or `.Children` in the second controller?

Comment: Children. Sorry I'll update that mistake

Comment: Try `.GetChildren()`. I'm not sure if this will help but if there is already and item in Sitecore cache and `.Children` was already called once, children list can be already populated and not refreshed after you add another child. `.GetChildren()` should execute call to the item provider.

Comment: Same issue with .GetChildren(). No items, if I hit the controller again later the item is returned.

Comment: Can you try to get the parent item again using the id of the `summaryFolder` and call `GetChildren()` on the new item? `Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(summaryFolder.ID).GetChildren()`?

Comment: Ive updated the question with the code. I'm calling GetItem first before GetChildren

Comment: Aye you sure about the execution order of your involved controllers?

Comment: You were right Mark, It was a controller execution order. Was a bug in the javascript, the second controller was being called before a success was returned from the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed by a suggestion by Mark Cassidy, this was due to the call order of the JavaScript hitting the wrong controller first.